# The second shortest path on a directed graph.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, algorithms

The question asks to write an algorithm using Dijkstra's algorithm with time complexity of

Θ(|E|  log⁡|V| ) that find the second shortest path between s∈V and t∈V.

The farthest I managed to get is:

1.Run Dijkstra's algorithm and find the path from $s$ to $t$. Mark this path as $P_{(s,t)}$.

2.Remove one edge $e' \in E$ in $P_{(s,t)}$.

3.Run Dijkstra's algorithm on $G' = (V, E - \{e'\})$ and find the path from $s$ to $t$. Mark this
path as $P'_{(s,t)}$.

4.Define $\text{secondMin} = |P'_{(s,t)}|$.

5.Define $\text{secondPath} = P'_{(s,t)}$.

6.for $i = 1$ to $|P_{(s,t)}| - 1$:

a. Remove one edge $e \neq e' \in E$.

b. Run Dijkstra's algorithm on $G'' = (V, E - \{e\})$ and find the path
from $s$ to $t$. Mark this path as $P''_{(s,t)}$.

c. if  $|P''_{(s,t)}|<$ secondMin  then secondMin = $|P''_{(s,t)}|$ and
secondPath = $P''_{(s,t)}.$

7. Return $\text{secondMin}$ and $\text{secondPath}$.

The time complexity of the algorithm is mainly achieved by the loop in line 6:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\Theta(|V|)} \Theta(|E| \log |V|) = \Theta(|V||E| \log |V|)$$

I will tell you where I got stuck:

[here is an example for a graph I tried to work with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gtOv.jpg)

It can be shown that each edge on the shortest path between s to y, is the shortest edge between two nodes in the path.
I can't see the point when Dijkstra's algorithm gives the second shortest path (if it does at all).

In order to get the second shortest path, I know that one green edge on the left need to be removed, but I don't know which one, so that why I use the loop in line 6.

Comment: Just a hint. Suppose you have a sequence of numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. How can you find the minimum? How can you find the second smallest number?

Comment: Hello! I know there is an algorithm called "Select" with a time complexity of (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) O(n).
I can also use the following process:
a. I scan the array for a minimum.
b. I scan the members in the array that are different from what I found in a.  and find the minimum for them. 
This process is also with a time complexity of O(n)

Comment: It is good for you that you know about quick select. But that's not in what we are interested here. We need a certain ad hoc solution for now. Let's add two restrictions: algorithm sees each element only once and has $O(1)$ of memory

Comment: min = secondMin = a[1].
for i = 2 to n-1
      if a[i+1] < a[i] then (a[i+1] = min and a[i] = secondMin)
return secondMin.
I'm sorry for thee spacing.

Comment: Looks like it returns the last element which is greater than next one to it, or the first element if the first one is minimum

Comment: Thank you for bringing my attention.
min = secondMin = a[1]. for i = 2 to n-1 if a[i] < min then (secondMin=min and min=a[i] ) return secondMin. I'm sorry for thee spacing.

Comment: You catch the general idea right, but implementation is still not correct. Look at some examples, like $1, 2, 3$, or $3, 1, 2$, or $2, 1, 1$

Comment: And you are ready to start thinking how you can apply similar idea to your problem

Comment: Thank you again. min = secondMin = a[1]. for i = 2 to n if a[i] < min then (secondMin=min and min=a[i] ) return secondMin.

Comment: Here is my attempt to use the idea you provided:
I will put aside the implementation part.
Let "second" be the variable that will contain all the information about the second shortest path from s to t.
In the first iteration of Dijkstra's algorithm, the distance between s and all the other nodes, t included, is ∞.
There for, we will let "second" know that the path from s to t is of a length ∞.
Each time during Dijkstra's algorithm that the path between s and t is shortening, we will update "second" to include the length of the path, and the path itself.

Comment: Because Dijkstra's algorithm gives the shortest path between s and t, we are guaranteed that will be a point the "second" will contain the information about the second shortest path between s and t (and of course that the process described above is finite).

Comment: Nevertheless, in order to discuss properly on the time complexity of the process described above we will need to dive into the implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm – the update of "second" in each iteration cost O(1), and there for will not effect the overall time complexity of Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: However, I can not prove why it is guaranteed that the second shortest path from s to t will appear during Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: You fixed an issue with $n - 1$ which I didn't notice. But it still gives wrong answer for all three examples above: your answers are $1$, $3$ and $2$ while correct answers are $2$, $2$ and $1$.

Comment: For the second shortest path problem you miss some important opportunity (at least it looks so). Try $G = (\{\,1, 2, 3, 4\,\}, \{\,\{\,1, 2\,\}, \{\,1, 3\,\}, \{\,2, 3\,\}, \{\,3, 4\,\}\,\})$ (with all edge weights equal to $1$) and $s = 1$, $t = 4$.

Comment: Thank you again.                                                                                                             
I didn't write the edge cases.
min = a[1]
secondMin = a[2]
for i = 3 to n
      if a[i] < secondMin
          then secondMin = a[i]
return max(a[1],secondMin)

Comment: I look at the graph G you provided. The shortest path from s to t is (s->3->t) and its length is 2.
The second shortest path from s to t is (s->2->3->t) and its length is 3. 
There are a lot of things that can be said (for example, the second shortest path starts with a different edge), but I don't feel comfortable claiming those things because of the size of G. Can you please look at the picture I provided in the question: I ran Dijkstra's algorithm so many times, because I didn't know which edge to remove in order to get the second shortest path. We can say that this is a greedy approach.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4816788/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/163227/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I give up giving hints, just write the full solution here.)

Firstly we consider a solution for the problem of the second smallest element in a sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ subject to reading each element once and having $\mathrm O(1)$ of additional memory.

Let's solve this problem not only for the whole sequence, but also for every its prefix. (Due to the limited amount of memory the answer for a certain prefix will exist for $\mathrm O(1)$ of time only.) We will also compute the minimum for each prefix.

Let's start with an empty sequence. Then both the minimum and the second smallest element are infinite: $m_1 \gets +\infty$, $m_2 \gets +\infty$.

If $m_1$ and $m_2$ are correspondingly the minimum and the second smallest element among the first $i - 1$ elements ($1 \le i \le n$), then for the first $i$ elements there are three options we need to distinguish: $a_i$ is the minimum (the answer is $(a_i, m_1)$), $a_i$ is the second smallest element (the answer is $(m_1, a_i)$) and $a_i$ is greater than the second smallest element (the answer is $(m_1, m_2)$). So we can firstly compare $a_i$ with $m_2$: if $a_i < m_2$ then $m_2 \gets a_i$. Secondly if $m_2 < m_1$ then swap them: $m_1 \leftrightarrows m_2$. Now $m_1$ and $m_2$ are correspondingly the minimum and the second smallest element among the first $i$ elements.

---

Now let's return to the problem of the second shortest path from $s$ to $t$. The main similarity with the previous problem is that we compute lengths of both shortest and the second shortest paths for each vertex $v$.

So for each vertex $v$ we start with infinite upper bounds on the lengths of both the shortest and the second shortest paths: $b_1(v) \gets \infty$, $b_2(v) \gets \infty$. The only exception is $b_1(s)$ which is $0$.

After that we repeatedly select minimum among non-frozen bounds (all $b_1$'s and $b_2$'s together), freeze it and relax along each outgoing arc (e. g., update bound for the head of the outgoing arc). Updating bounds is completely the same as updating $m_1$ and $m_2$ in the problem of the second smallest element. (Note that it is not possible to update $b_1(u)$ using $b_2(v)$ if $b_1(v) < b_2(v)$, because in such case $b_1(u)$ would be already updated with a smaller number.)

In this way we twice more times select minimum among twice more bound, and relaxation along each outgoing arc will be produced twice. So the total time with binary heap is $\mathrm O(2n \cdot \log 2n + 2m \cdot \log 2n) = \mathrm O((n + m) \log n)$, where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ is the number of arcs. If $n = \mathrm O(m)$, that is the case particularly for connected graphs, then it can be simplified to $\mathrm O(m \log n)$. Note that the multiplication constant under big-$\mathrm O$ is at least twice higher, than for the shortest path length.

To reconstruct the second shortest path itself it is possible either saving last successful incoming relaxation for each vertex, or starting from the end search for the previous vertex of the path traversing each incoming arc in the opposite direction. The first option increases the multiplication constant in total time, while the second one adds extra $\mathrm O(m + n)$ time. But the first option allows to reconstruct multiple paths faster, than the second one.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the time and the effort, I really appreciate it. Wishing you all the best !!

Comment: @Daniel you may say thank you by upvoting and accepting if you deem it worthy.